# Как узнать что AsynkTask отработал?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask

В моем приложение есть несколько отдельных AsynkTask задач, запускаемых мной в UI. LoadDataFromServerTask() - загружает данные с сервера. SaveDataToDBTask() - сохраняет данные во внутреннюю базу. Запустить вторую задачу мне нужно после того, как я получу результат выполнения первой задачи. То есть:

```
LoadDataFromServerTask().execute
SaveDataToDBTask().execute
```

Но в таком варианте выполнение второго задания начинается сразу после старта выполнения первого. Как мне добиться нужного результат без замораживания UI, учитывая что обе задачи являются универсальными, т.е. не связанными друг с другом и использующимися по отдельности в других местах моего кода?

```
LoadDataFromServerTask().execute
//// Ждем результат выполнения LoadDataFromServerTask()
SaveDataToDBTask().execute
```

Решение засунуть  SaveDataToDBTask() в onPostExecute LoadDataFromServerTask() не подходит. Нужен какой-то listener для LoadDataFromServerTask() запускающий SaveDataToDBTask(),но я не понимаю как это реализовать.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что сохранить данные с сервера нужно только при определенных условиях? Тогда что мешает передавать в LoadDataFromServerTask boolean и в onPostExecute проверять его?

Comment: Камрад не хочет слушать советы бывалых... или не понимает, как кодировать в event driven среде

Answer (score 1):

Вызывайте свой `SaveDataToDBTask` в методе
`onPostExecute()` у `LoadDataFromServerTask`

Comment: Использование вашего метода автоматически подразумевает запуск SaveDataToDBTask() по окончанию LoadDataFromServerTask(), что не актуально, так как результаты выполнения LoadDataFromServerTask используется в других местах кода не взаимосвязано с SaveDataToDBTask()

Comment: @SergeyValuikin кто запрещает использовать глобальную переменную для хранения результатов первой функции?

Comment: Но тогда для запуска SaveDataToDBTask() нужно условие проверяющие значение этой переменной и я не понимаю, как реализовать такое условие, учитываю что результат выполнения LoadDataFromServerTask() выдает огромный и сложный ArrayList<Objects>

Comment: И опять же, если запихнуть  SaveDataToDBTask()  в цикл while, он будет замораживать UI на время выполнения LoadDataFromServerTask() .

Comment: @SergeyValuikin, Вы запускаете `LoadDataFromServerTask` несколько раз, и только в одном случае нужно сохранить результат в базу, или в чём загвоздка?